# Chrome for iOS vs. <style>height: 100vh;</style>

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, google-chrome

Chrome for iOS hides its address bar when the user scrolls up. This feature does not work well with `100vh` (or any `vh` unit) because as the toolbar shrinks, the viewport height changes and thus the size of the element changes. I have a cover image with `100vh` and it causes a very noticeable jitter as the length of the entire page grows or shrinks.

The problem exists for any height set with `vh`, I think.

I can (and probably will) resort to javascript to set my cover image height, but I'd prefer to use `vh`.

Any clever ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using 100% instead of 100vh - you can add this...

```
body{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
```

From there, any element without another wrapper that has its own height will be able to fill the full screen just using width and height at 100%. Example below!

https://codepen.io/will0220/pen/KXqoGZ